# SharePoint + E-commerce =?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

My question is: Is it common for SharePoint 2010 and 2013 to be used as a e-commerce website for end-user?

Comment: it would be more appropriate to post this in the Chat area and solicit responses.  that being said there are plenty of sites using SharePoint for this purpose, but I'm not sure I would classify it as "common".

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not common. SharePoint does not come with any e-commerce functionality out of the box. That needs to be brought in by other software. A quick google for "SharePoint shopping cart" should give you some ideas about third party products. Microsoft also has a server product for e-commerce, but I have heard (cannot quote any sources) that it's hard to install and integrate with SharePoint.

In 2013 the Catalogue functionality looks like a step into the e-commerce direction.

The whole bundle about payment transactions, etc., is not in the box.

Answer (score 0):

If your customer is using latest AX and SharePoint 2013 there is AX Retail that is a standard commerce integration for SharePoint 2013

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj991926.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link where you can find an overview of SharePoint Ecommerce Services

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd464270.aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd328216.aspx